# Error Order by clause in sql server function

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have sql server query function with join to other tables and i got some error

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMutationUnGrouped]     
    (   
        -- Add the parameters for the function here
        @startDate Date, 
        @endDate Date,
        @PlaceId nvarchar(128)



    )
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN (
        SELECT mut.*,inv.Barcode, itm.ItemName,plc.PlaceName,loc.ItemLocationName,sub.ItemSubLocationName,inv.BuyDate,inv.Cost,typ.TypeName

        FROM ItemInventoryMutation mut 
        JOIN ItemInventory inv ON mut.ItemInventoryId = inv.Id
        JOIN Items itm ON inv.itemId = itm.Id
        JOIN ItemTypes typ ON itm.ItemTypesId = typ.Id
        JOIN ItemSubLocations sub ON mut.ItemSublocationId = sub.Id
        JOIN ItemLocations loc ON sub.ItemLocationsId = loc.Id
        JOIN Place plc ON loc.PlaceId = plc.Id


        WHERE (inv.BuyDate >= @startDate AND inv.BuyDate <= @endDate) AND  (inv.itemId IS NOT NULL AND inv.IsDelete = 0) AND loc.PlaceId = @PlaceId
        ORDER BY mut.Id ASC, mut.MutationDate DESC

    )
```

what is causing the error? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is exactly what the error message says - you cannot use `ORDER BY` in your return table definition unless you specify `TOP`.

I'm guessing you don't want to specify `TOP` in this case and want to return all records. In this case, you should return not ordered records from your `[dbo].[GetMutationUnGrouped]` function and order them when you use the function.

You can find more info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx):

> The ORDER BY clause is not valid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, and subqueries, unless either the TOP or OFFSET and FETCH
>   clauses are also specified. When ORDER BY is used in these objects,
>   the clause is used only to determine the rows returned by the TOP
>   clause or OFFSET and FETCH clauses. The ORDER BY clause does not
>   guarantee ordered results when these constructs are queried, unless
>   ORDER BY is also specified in the query itself.

So if you wanted to get ordered records from your function, that won't work - you will have to order records again anyway, even if you specify `TOP` in your function.